# Trouble programming for school

Tags: c

I am coding a workshop for my class (I am a complete beginner), and I am having some problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define arraylength 100

void GetInt();
void GetFloar();

int main (void)
{
    int i, k, j;

    float price[arraylength];
    int barcode[arraylength];
    int quantity[arraylength];
    int lenght;
    printf("Grocery Store Inventory\n");
    printf("=======================\n");

    for (i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
        printf("Barcode: ");
        scanf("%d", &barcode[i]);
        GetInt;
    }

    if (barcode[i] == 0)
        break;

    printf("Price: ");
    scanf("%f", &price[i]);
    printf("Quantity: ");
    scanf("%d", &quantity[i]);
    return 0;
}

void GetInt()
{
    int number;

    printf("Barcode: ");
    while (scanf("%d", &number != 1)){
        printf("Wrong Input , Try Again!\n");
        printf("Insert Correct Barcode:\n");
        while(getchar() != "\n");
    }
    return number;
}

void GetFloat()
{
    float number;
    printf("Barcode: ");
    while (scanf("%d", &number != 1)){
        printf("Wrong Input , Try Again!\n");
        printf("Insert Correct Barcode:\n");
        while (getchar() != "\n");
    }
    return number;
}
```

I keep getting these errors:

```
work.c: In function ‘main’:
work.c:23:5: error: break statement not within loop or switch
work.c: In function ‘GetInt’:
work.c:35:26: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
work.c:38:18: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
work.c:40:3: warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void [enabled by default]
work.c: In function ‘GetFloat’:
work.c:45:26: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
work.c:48:25: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
work.c:50:7: warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void [enabled by default]
```

Can someone tell me what is happening and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Compile with warnings: `void GetFloar();` --> `void GetFloat();` , `GetInt;` --> `GetInt();`

Comment: Hint: the error messages all have a filename, line number and column number, e.g. `work.c:23:5` is line 23 column 5 in "work.c". BTW, spending a little time to format your code properly makes it a lot easier to see the errors.

Comment: Well, you can't break from main, for one.

Comment: Something seems very wrong after you exit the for loop in main. i should be equal to arraylength after that, but you access all the arrays with i, which accesses past the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to point out all the errors I can see in your code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define arraylength 100
//this might as well be: const int arraylength = 100;

void GetInt();
void GetFloar(); //this is spelled wrong

int main (void)
{
    int i, k, j;

    float price[arraylength];
    int barcode[arraylength];
    int quantity[arraylength];
    int lenght; //this is spelled wrong
    printf("Grocery Store Inventory\n");
    printf("=======================\n");

    for (i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
        printf("Barcode: ");
        scanf("%d", &barcode[i]);
        GetInt; //this does nothing; to call GetInt, use GetInt()
    }

    if (barcode[i] == 0) // i == arraylength here so this is illegal
        break; //you can only break from a loop or a switch statement

    printf("Price: ");
    scanf("%f", &price[i]); // i == arraylength here so this is illegal
    printf("Quantity: ");
    scanf("%d", &quantity[i]); // i == arraylength here so this is illegal
    return 0; 
}

void GetInt() //this should be declared as int GetInt(void)
{
    int number;

    printf("Barcode: ");
    while (scanf("%d", &number != 1)){ 
    //&number != -1 is not a valid parameter for scanf
    //Seems like it should be scanf("%d", &number) != 1
        printf("Wrong Input , Try Again!\n");
        printf("Insert Correct Barcode:\n");
        while(getchar() != "\n");
    }
    return number; //you can't return from a void function
}

void GetFloat() //this should be declared float GetFloat(void)
{
    float number;
    printf("Barcode: ");
    while (scanf("%d", &number != 1)){ 
    //&number != -1 is not a valid parameter for scanf
    //also you have the integer format string there
    //Seems like it should be scanf("%f", &number) != 1
        printf("Wrong Input , Try Again!\n");
        printf("Insert Correct Barcode:\n");
        while (getchar() != "\n");
    }
    return number; //you can't return from a void function
}
```

You should use doubles instead of floats. I'm not sure where floats are useful, apart from graphics processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have return values in functions, they cannot be void, they need to be int (in your case):

```
int GetInt();
int GetFloat();
```

Your scanf() function is incorret because you cannot compare value in it, it needs to be:

```
while(scanf("%d", &number) != 1)
```

on GetInt() function and:

```
while(scanf("%f", &number) != 1)
```

on GetFloat() because you are working with floats.
In main() function you are breaking nothing, that's an error. Your code needs to be:

```
for (i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
   printf("Barcode: ");
   scanf("%d", &barcode[i]);
   GetInt();
   if (barcode[i] == 0){
      break;
   }else{
       printf("Price: ");
       scanf("%f", &price[i]);
       printf("Quantity: ");
       scanf("%d", &quantity[i]);
   }
}
```

With some basic arrangements.

Comment: I think he meant the next 4 lines to be in the for loop as well

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I didn't note that.